# NSAttributedString font not overriding xib font the first time the cell is loaded

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib, nsattributedstring

I have a tableview cell with a label. In the xib file for the cell, I have a small font set on this label. In my `cellForRow` method, I am setting the label's attributedText property to some string using a large font. When my view controller loads, it initially uses the small font specified in the xib. When I scroll the cell out of view and scroll it back into view (i.e. reload the cell), the correct large font is used. How can I have it adopt the correct font on first load as well?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      //initialize/dequeue cell from table
      [cell configureLabelWith:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi!"
                                                            attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0]}];
```

```
- (void)configureLabelWith:(NSAttributedString *)title {
    self.label.attributedText = title;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the view controller's tableview calls `layoutSubviews` after it calls `cellForRow`. When laying the subviews, it reverts the label properties back to what was specified in the xib (not sure if this is standard behavior). As a workaround I store the attributed string in the cell and override it again in `traitCollectionDidChange` which occurs after the cell is laid out, so I made the following changes to the cell class

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSAttributedString *labelAttributedString;`

```
- (void)configureLabelWith:(NSAttributedString *)title {
    self.labelAttributedString = title;
    self.label.attributedText = self.labelAttributedString;
```

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];
    [self configureLabelWith:self.labelAttributedString];
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue on iOS 13, only 11 and 12